# Deepnet package outputs probabilities outside the desired range

Tags: r, neural-network

Im using `deepnet` to do a classification. Everything in the dataset is numeric. I train my model using the command below:

```
library(deepnet)
dnn <- dbn.dnn.train(training, y_training, hidden = rep(100,50,30),numepochs = 5, learningrate = 0.5, hidden_dropout = 0.3)

prednn <- nn.predict(dnn, testing)
range(prednn)
[1] 0.7167986 0.9834596
```

Everything is fine but when i predict using `deepnet` i get output in the mentioned range. Am i not supposed to get output between 0 and 1 which i can the split based on a cutoff such as 0.5. Or is there anything that i havent specified in the model.

**Update**
Using very low learning rate i get even worse result.

```
dnn <- dbn.dnn.train(training, y_training, hidden = rep(100,50,30),numepochs = 5, learningrate = 0.1, hidden_dropout = 0.3)

 range(prednn)
[1] 0.8619268 0.8619268
```

Comment: Did the neural network actually converged to a low loss? Seems not, your learning rate is too big, you should train a network properly before looking at its predictions.

Comment: I tried setting learning rate to 0.2 which got my range down `range(prednn)
[1] 0.6600011 0.9710593` but im unable to get proper predictions.

Comment: Learning rate is typically lower still around 0.1, 0.01, or even lower yet.  Also, you are only training for 5 epochs.  Many models take much longer than that to adequately learn the data.